# How to show added events in Android default Calendar

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

This is the code that I have used to add `Calendar` events, it's working fine.
But I can't see the events that I have added. The code doesn't have any errors.

```
CalendarView cal = (CalendarView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
//Context ctx;
ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
event.put("calendar_id", R.id.calendarView1);
event.put("title", "WOOT");
event.put("description", "Wootification");
event.put("eventLocation", "Wootness");
event.put("allDay", 0); 
event.put("eventStatus", 1);
//event.put("visibility", 0);
//event.put("transparency", 0);
// event.put(Events.VISIBLE, 1);
event.put("hasAlarm", 0);

Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.set(2015, 4, 27, 8, 0, 0);

Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.set(2015, 4, 30, 9, 0, 0);

long startTime = start.getTimeInMillis();       
// startTime = startTime * 1000;

long endTime = end.getTimeInMillis();
// endTime = endTime * 1000;
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
event.put("dtstart", startTime);
event.put("dtend", endTime);
System.out.println(startTime);
System.out.println(endTime);
// insert event to calendar
Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI.toString());
cr.insert(eventsUri, event);
System.out.println(event);
// add 10 minute reminder for the event
ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
reminders.put(Reminders.EVENT_ID, R.id.calendarView1);
reminders.put(Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
reminders.put(Reminders.MINUTES, 1);

Uri eventsUrir = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/reminders");
cr.insert(eventsUrir, reminders);
```

Can someone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Anyone have any solutions for this?.......

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you have not got any solution.

Use following method to add, Remove and delete Event from default Calendar.

```
public void addEvent(Context context) {
        GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(this._year, this._month, this._day, this._hour, this._minute);

        try {
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calDate.getTimeInMillis());
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calDate.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, this._title);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeZone().getID());
            System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());
            Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

            // Save the eventId into the Task object for possible future delete.
            this._eventId = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            // Add a 5 minute, 1 hour (2 reminders)
            setReminder(cr, this._eventId, 5);
            setReminder(cr, this._eventId, 60);    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
// routine to add reminders with the event
public void setReminder(ContentResolver cr, long eventID, int timeBefore) {
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, timeBefore);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI, values);
        Cursor c = CalendarContract.Reminders.query(cr, eventID,
                new String[]{CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES});
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            System.out.println("calendar"
                    + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES)));
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//use following method to remove an event from the calendar using the eventId stored within the Task object.
public void removeEvent(Context context) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    int iNumRowsDeleted = 0;

    Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse(CALENDAR_URI_BASE+"events");
    Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, this._eventId);
    iNumRowsDeleted = cr.delete(eventUri, null, null);

    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Deleted " + iNumRowsDeleted + " calendar entry.");
}


public int updateEvent(Context context) {
    int iNumRowsUpdated = 0;
    GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar(this._year, this._month, this._day, this._hour, this._minute);

    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();

    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, this._title);
    event.put("hasAlarm", 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, calDate.getTimeInMillis());
    event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calDate.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);

    Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse(CALENDAR_URI_BASE+"events");
    Uri eventUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, this._eventId);

    iNumRowsUpdated = context.getContentResolver().update(eventUri, event, null,
            null);

    // TODO put text into strings.xml
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Updated " + iNumRowsUpdated + " calendar entry.");

    return iNumRowsUpdated;
}
```